# What is occurring at this bind in C++?

Tags: c++, function, boost-bind, stdbind

I know that this is simple code, but I can't find amazingly detailed documentation anywhere for the project or on C++'s bind. This is the code:

```
uri.canonize(bind(&FaceController::onCanonizeSuccess, this, _1, onSuccess, onFailure, uri),
             bind(&FaceController::onCanonizeFailure, this, _1, onSuccess, onFailure, uri),
             m_ioService, TIME_ALLOWED_FOR_CANONIZATION);
```

I've only ever used bind with one more argument than the bound function, not with two. Additionally, `uri.canonize` has this function signature:

```
void
FaceUri::canonize(const CanonizeSuccessCallback& onSuccess,
              const CanonizeFailureCallback& onFailure,
              boost::asio::io_service& io, const time::nanoseconds& timeout) const
```

And much further down the rabbit hole, `onSuccess` and `onFailure` *do* get called with one argument, but I don't think it's important to show all that here. Finally, the function signature for `onCanonizeSuccess` is:

```
void
FaceController::onCanonizeSuccess(const FaceUri& uri,
                              const CommandSuccessCallback& onSuccess,
                              const CommandFailureCallback& onFailure,
                              const FaceUri& request)
```

Really I'm just asking for someone to interpret this with me. Here's what I have understood:
`uri.canonize` is being passed 4 arguments:

1. A bound function, which is of the return type `FaceController::onCanonizeSuccess`, with the first arg bound to the `uri` object, the second arg passed to the bound function, then `onSuccess`, `onFailure`, and `uri`.
2. A bound function just like above, except the return type is `FaceController::onCanonizeFailure`.
3. `m_ioService`
4. `TIME_ALLOWED_FOR_CANONIZATION`

So what this means is that `FaceUri::canonize` here is being passed two function objects that each take 1 argument, and two other things. Then, when `FaceUri::canonize` ultimately calls its `onSuccess` with that one argument, since that function object is bound to a return type of `FaceController::onCanonizeSuccess`, that's the function that will be called.

That's my best attempt at understanding what's going on here. The only issue is that `FaceController::onCanonizeSuccess` isn't the bound function. It can't be, because the arity here means we're calling `bind` with a return type, and `this` is the function to bind to. What is `this` in this context? The top-most calling function? `uri`? `uri.canonize`? This is all as clear as mud. Unfortunately, I don't know which bind we're using, but I believe it is std::bind, since I see a using std::bind clause a few includes up.

Comment: your understanding is correct.

Comment: But I still don't understand what "this" is doing here. What is that bound to?

Comment: OnCanonizeSuccess is a member function. It's binding to the "this" pointer.

Comment: I just don't follow. What does "this" indicate in the context it's placed in?

Comment: It's saying "when you call onCanonizeSuccess, call it on the same object that I am calling you from" Ie it's binding the callback to the current object context.

Comment: In C++, non-static member functions have an implicit `this` parameter -- a pointer to the object on which they are being invoked. If we have `A c;` and then `c.foo(1);`, that's kind of like `A::foo(this, 1)`.

Comment: That's exactly right, and now that's so clear. I don't know why that tripped me up so badly, because it's a pretty common occurrence. I feel a little embarrassed, but thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,
`void FaceUri::canonize` is a function, which gets called. It accepts four arguments, being (with proper cv and ref qualifiers)
`CanonizeSuccessCallback` - a function, which gets called (guessing from the name, on success)
`CanonizeFailureCallback` - a function, which gets called (guessing from the name, on failure)
and two plain arguments, you probably understand.

Now, `Canonize*Callback` are probably objects (guessing templates), which supposes, to have proper `operator()` defined on them. I suppose you know the basics behind `std::bind`.

And `uri.canonize` is a *function call*, where first two arguments are *functions*, to be called when canonizing succeeds or fails.

According to `onCanonizeSuccess` singature, you have to pass four parameters to `std::bind` for that function. Well, actually, since that function is not static, it requires fifth (or rather null-th) argument of type `FaceController*` on which should the function (`onCanonizeSuccess`) be called.

```
bind(
  &FaceController::onCanonizeSuccess, // non-static member function requiring first argument to be pointer to FaceController instance
  this, // pointer to FaceController instance, that means, the object with function, where uri.canonize is called.
  _1, // actually std::placeholders::_1, meaning, that first argument will be passed when calling bound function                                                                                                             
  onSuccess, // rest of parameters
  onFailure,
  uri
)
```

Comment: The comments are really what made this clear. I really appreciate the thorough, quick answers. Keep up the good work and keep helping idiots like me learn! Thanks!